# UIMA pos tagger invalid output

Tags: uima, pos-tagger

I gave two inputs to UIMA tagger.
1) JOHN IS VERY HAPPY TODAY.
2) john is very happy today.

in case 1) every thing turns out to be a Name and in second nothing turns out to be a name.
Can some one please help me in the same?

Comment: What exactly is the "UIMA tagger"?

Answer (score 0):

POS taggers tend to be a) case sensitive and b) fall back to noun. Thus what probably happens is this: for 1), it knows none of the words and falls back to noun. For 2) it does not recognize "John" as a name because it does not start with a capital letter and believes it to be something else.